# How to fix a python issue about PiCamera Module with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

For my school project, I have to detect a Rubik's Cube and its 6 surfaces thanks to a picamera. I've decided to do it with OpenCv and a python script.
Here is my code:

```
import cv2
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera

camera=PiCamera()
rawCapture=PiRGBArray(camera)


camera.capture(rawCapture,format='bgr')
image=rawCapture.array

cv2.imwrite('IMAGE.jpg',image)
```

Unfortunately the shell shows me this:

```
pi@LM-rasp:~/Documents $ python3 captureImage.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "captureImage.py", line 3, in <module>
    from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
  File "/home/pi/Documents/picamera.py", line 3, in <module>
    from picamera import PiCamera 
ImportError: cannot import name 'PiCamera'
```

I know it exists the same kind of issue for other people, but I don't succeed to fix this issue.
Can you help me ?
Thanks !

Comment: How did you install picamera module? what python version are you using? include the installation procedure in your post.

Comment: @Ziri First of all, thanks for the answer.  My python version is 3.4.3. And then I don't understand your first question. I've just connected my picamera onto my RPI. What should I do ?

Comment: make sure you picamera module is installed first: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md                                           sudo apt install python3-picamera

Comment: @Ziri my picamera module is actually well installed. To be sure that it's well installed I've executed the command you asked me to do.

Comment: Try                                                                   
 #import picamera                                                                              
#camera = picamera.PiCamera()

Comment: I tried your code but I have always the same issue :                                ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "captureImage.py", line 3, in <module>
    from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
  File "/home/pi/Documents/picamera.py", line 3, in <module>
    from picamera import PiCamera 
ImportError: cannot import name 'PiCamera' ```

Comment: A good basic check that the h/w (cable) and OS (`sudo raspi-config` and enable camera) are set up correctly is to take a quick photo with `raspistill` command.

Comment: Yes I have already done it, and it works with this command. But for OpenCv, it's still not...

Answer (score 0):

In the command line, first try:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall picamera
```

And then do:

```
sudo pip3 install picamera
```

That should do the job for you!

Comment: I was just doing it, but it fails again... I still have the same issue than previously.

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, the python shell replies with ```picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources```

Comment: I personally recommend this link: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-picamera

Comment: I succeeded to take a photo with raspistill, but when I try to execute the python script indicated in the link, I find back the same issue.

Comment: Moreover, when I try `sudo pip3 install picamera` I have this new issue:                    `WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x74dc16d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Échec temporaire dans la résolution du nom',)': /simple/picamera/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement picamera (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for picamera`.